# Is there a way to not change camera angles?

Tags: nier-automata

I've recently just started playing *Nier: Automata* and whilst I'm enjoying it the forced change of camera angles can be annoying at times.

Is there a way to stop this so I only have the rear third person camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to disable the forced camera angles in certain places, like overhead shots or sidescrolling segments. These are an integral part of the game experience and the gameplay would be very different without them.